# hitCallback - Workaround if the Chinese Firewall blocks Google

Tags: google-analytics

I've researched but found some old information, and not exactly on topic. Also, my dev team is completely overworked and speak Chinese only, so I want to get as much work out of their hand.

We use universal analytics.

I have a multi-session goal. Users complete the sign up process, and an activation e-mail is sent to their account. After they click this link, they'll reach an ActivationSuccess page which immediately forwards them to the home center of the log in part.

Problem right now is that the forward goes too fast for GA to recognize the hit. I'm thinking about alternative solutions, and I think the hitCallback function is the best option.

My only concern is that if I add the hitCallback function and The Chinese Great Firewall blocks google, the Callback will never be made.

I'm thinking about different solutions, which will impact the user as little as possible, in order of preference:

1. Add the hitCallback, and know that Google will forward even if analytics.js can't reach the google page (this is my main question), or set a timeout.
2. Add the hitCallback + a 'click here' tag so that IF the callback doesn't come the user can manually forward himself, without sending the GA code.
3. Add a 3-second delay before auto-forwarding. This will surely fire the analytics.js script, but will impact the user experience heavily.
4. Add cookie tracking method: Add a cookie on the ActivatedSuccess page and retroactively send this in the next page. This is maybe the most elegant way, but requires more coding and a deeper understanding of GA than my Chinese dev team has.

So, I have three questions:

1. Will the hitCallback function still work if the host can't access Google?
2. Is it possible to create a timeout so that if users wait for more than 300 MS they get forwarded anyway?
3. Of my possible solutions, which one do you think would be the best, knowing that I have limited knowledge of coding and my dev team can't read Chinese?

(We don't use Baidu analytics, because that slows the page way down for users outside of China; up to 45 (!) seconds because they don't support asynchronous loading, Google works faster in China than Baidu in the West).

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just for clarification: "Your (chinese) dev team can't read chinese" (third question) is that a typo ?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. They can't read English and apparently the Chinese translation is not up to snuff..

Answer (score 2):

Try This.  It checks to see if GA is loaded. If not you can still place the redirect in the else.
https://www.domsammut.com/code/workaround-for-when-the-hitcallback-function-does-not-receive-a-response-analytics-js